# Aggregate DataFrame over Index

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, geopandas

I have following DataFrame

```
                    (polygon object)     ASSAULT     BURGLARY   bank     cafe    crossing
INCIDENTDATE                                                                            
2009-01-01 02:00:00                A           1           0       0        1           0
2009-01-01 02:00:00                A           1           0       0        1           0
2009-01-01 02:00:00                A           1           0       1        0           0
2009-01-01 02:00:00                A           1           0       0        0           1
2009-01-01 02:00:00                A           1           0       0        1           0
2009-01-04 11:00:00                B           0           1       1        0           0
2009-01-04 11:00:00                B           0           1       1        0           0
2009-01-04 11:00:00                B           0           1       0        0           0
2009-01-04 11:00:00                B           0           1       1        0           0
2009-01-04 11:00:00                B           0           1       0        1           0
```

I want to aggregate that DataFrame to only have unique `'INCIDENTDATE'`

while doing this I want the value of each column (except polygon) to be 1 if it was 1 in at least one row of same `'INCIDENTDATE'` rows.

The final DataFrame should look like this:

```
                    (polygon object)    ASSAULT     BURGLARY    bank     cafe    crossing
INCIDENTDATE                                                                            
2009-01-01 02:00:00                A           1           0       1        1           1
2009-01-04 11:00:00                B           0           1       1        1           0
```

How would i achieve that in pandas?
Googling my question pointed me to the groupby() function but I really dont understand how i would use it here.

Comment: You can group dataframe by index, df.groupby(df.index).max()

Answer (score 3):

I think just reset in the index then groupby that new column and look for the max values of each group:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.groupby('INCIDENTDATE').max()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `max` function should do this:

```
df.groupby("INCIDENTDATE").agg("max")
```